# Click sign-in button

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell command to click on this button and nothing seems to work, it's driving me crazy, any help would be great!

```html
<input name="sign_in_button" type="submit" value="Go">
```

This is what I tried, but no luck:

```bsh
$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("sign_in_button") |
        Where-Object {$_.Type -eq "submit"}
$Link.Click();
```

Comment: `Document.getElementsByTagName()` gets the Tag Name ( in this case `input`), not `name="sign_in_button`. try `Document.getElementsByTagName("input")`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` -> `getElementsByName()`. Tag name (`<input>`) and element name (attribute `name="..."`) are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your feedback! I realized I messed up, hence don't work so late as your brain losses function! This was my fix the next am:

$Link=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "submit"}
$Link.click();

Answer (score -1):

The way I do it is as follow:

```
($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("LOGON_BUTTON") | Select-Object -First 1).Click()
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: As Ansgar pointed out, your element does not have an ID. So, either you add an ID Tag to your element, or you try something like this:

```
($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByName("sign_in_button") | Select-Object -First 1).Click()
```

or

```
($ie.Document.getElementByName("sign_in_button") | Select-Object -First 1).Click()
```

Comment: That would require the button to have an attribute `id="LOGON_BUTTON"`, which it apparently doesn't.